# Intent.createChooser android QR code reader

Tags: java, android, android-intent, qr-code, zxing

I want the user to choose a QR reader from his installed apps. This could be done by using the Intent.createChooser. When a picture is taken with the QR reader, the QR code should be sent back to my application. This is what Ive tried so far:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

            String title = (String) getResources().getText(R.string.chooser_title);

            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

            startActivityForResult(chooser, CUSTOM_REQUEST_QR_SCANNER);
```

The scanner doens't start correctly, it only shows an sample QR code. I have a feeling the intent.setType("text/plain") might be wrong? What type is a QR reader? Or how do i start a QR reader this way correctly?

I also have an ActivityResult when the QR app is done:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == CUSTOM_REQUEST_QR_SCANNER) {

        Log.d(TAG, "QR activity complete");
                        //Successful scan
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

Comment: i don't see how 'SEND' 'text/plain' can ever be resolved as a qr_code request

Comment: are you using any library for this like zxing or zbar??

Comment: You are right, I should probably use zxing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

with

```
intent.setType("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow This [Demo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing) and do include "**android-integration.jar**" in your project it has this .jar file also... and also you can download Zxing Library from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list) it will use the available QR Code Scanner in your app. There are also other ways just use this first  you will get to know other also by R and D.

**OR**

Use this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        Button btn_scan =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
        btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                  integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (result != null) {
          String contents = result.getContents();
          if (contents != null) {
            showDialog("Found QRcode", result.toString());
          } else {
            showDialog("NO QRcode Found", "The user gave up and pressed Back");
          }
        }
    }

    private void showDialog(String title, CharSequence message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.show();
      }
```

and include same .jar file in project properties java build path. you can download .jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list) same link.